# how to pass jsx as a string inside the return call

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Is it possible to do something like:

```
const data={
star: "<h1>STAR</h1>",
moon: "<h3>moon</h3>"
}

const App = () => {
return(
<div>{data.start}</div>
);
}
```

what i get is the actual string of `<h1>STAR</h1>` not just `STAR`

Comment: Sounds like you may want [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

Comment: Unfortunately it will remain as a string, unless you remove the quotation marks.

Comment: @kinduser  i cannow as in real work i have start: "<h1>start</h1><h2>nice</h2>" and if remove the quotation it start naging about having 2 things infront of :

Comment: So it seems like Oliver is right and it's the only way to go.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth  thanks can you add it as an answer?

Comment: @farmcommand you can remove those warnings by wrapping the entire thing in a `span` or `div` if that's possible for you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.  You can return an html string and possibly get it to display, but JSX isn't a string, it gets compiled into javscript code that creates those elements.  it works when your app is built, I don't think you can use dynamic strings with it at run-time.  You could do something like this:

```
const getData = (which) => {
  if (which === 'star') {
    return (<h1>STAR</h1>);
  }
  if (which === 'moon') {
    return (<h3>moon</h3>);
  }
  return null; // nothing will display
}


const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>{getData('star')}</div>
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i knew it that way, i want to use that object file as my config

Comment: @farmcommand well if you wanted to do that you can save the JSX in a component, then have the object values be those components, like save the star in `A.jsx`, then in your config: `import A from "A.jsx"; const x = {star: A}`. Then you can use it when you import x, e.g. `<div>{React.createElement(x.star)}</div>`. Something like that should work

Answer (score 0):

Strings can be converted to JSX with third-party libraries such as [`h2x`](https://github.com/smooth-code/h2x) or [`react-render-html`](https://github.com/utatti/react-render-html). It may be unsafe to do this with user input because of possible vulnerabilities and security problems that may exist libraries that parse DOM.

It's impossible to use components this way because component names aren't associated with functions that implement them during conversion.